# Have to continuously delete/add ssh key to github

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I've been having this strange issue. I just recently upgraded my mac to sierra and I generated a new ssh key for github.

The problem is, I add my ssh key to gihub and it works for like 15mins and then after that I get an error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I end up doing

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And I delete the ssh key in github and add again. I have to keep doing this every 15 mins. Does anyone have any clue what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely Mac Sierra related, as can be [read here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/upgrading-to-macos-sierra-will-break-your-ssh-keys-and-lock-you-out-of-your-own-servers-f413ac96139a).

Generate a new key using

```
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you receive a reply starting with something like *2048 SHA256*, you should be good to go. Just copy it to github.

If not, you have to run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and do as you proposed to do. I had the same problem and Quincy's explanation helped me alot.

Comment: I followed the steps and the problem still remains. I am using it with github enterprise. Maybe its an issue with that. I also noticed my ssh keys have 'never used' written in the ssh keys page of github like after 15 mins. This is very puzzling.